# Can anyone explain why this works in java 7 and not java 6?

Tags: java

I'm using this code:

```
public static void printMap(Map<Integer, String> obj) {
        for (Map.Entry e : obj.entrySet()) {
            if (e.getKey() == 3) {
                System.out.println("OK!");
            }
        }
    }
```

and it works in Java 7. But in Java 6 it gives an error on the line:

```
if (e.getKey() == 3) {
```

Can anyone explain to me why I get this error?

Comment: What kind of error specifically?

Comment: In an earlier version I'd say it's an autoboxing problem. But Java 6 does support autoboxing. Are you sure it's actually Java 6?

Comment: It's because you can't == an object to a primitive. Java7 understands it is an Integer and will auto-unbox it, but Java6 will need you to parametrise the `Entry`.

Comment: You are not using Generic type while getting Map.Entry .. It should be `Map.Entry<Integer,String> e` for version before java version before below 7

Comment: The e.getKey return object and compared with 3 without type cast! This  works in java 7, but in 6 it give error!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In java 6, you need to specify the types for your `Map.Entry` variable

```
Map.Entry<Integer, String> e : obj.entrySet()
```

before you compare the key or value of such an `Entry`. Otherwise the compiler thinks you are doing

```
if (<object of type Object> == 3)
```

which makes no sense to it.

Comment: So, this is new resource of Java 7, is not?

Comment: Yes, you can look at [type inference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably you need to assign a type to your `Entry`:

```
public static void printMap(Map<Integer, String> obj) {
    for (Map.Entry<Integer, String> e : obj.entrySet()) {
        if (e.getKey() == 3) {
            System.out.println("OK!");
        }
    }
}
```

There are changes in Java 7 to the generics framework. I am not sure whether that code would, as you suggest, work in Java 7 but I can say that you need to specify the generic types of `Entry` for it to work in Java 6.

Answer (score 0):

Its a template problem in Java 6 I think.

This fixes it:

> public static void printMap(Map obj) {
>
> ```
>     for (Map.Entry<Integer, String> e : obj.entrySet()) {
>         if (e.getKey() == 3) {
>             System.out.println("OK!");
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

Java 6 doesn't auto pass the arguments from the Map to the Map.Entry

Answer (score -2):

Try this

```
if (e.getKey().toString().equals("3"))
```

I think `e.getKey()` returns an object and you were comparing it with integer. Either convert it to integer and compare or to String and compare

Comment: The method is `toString()` and you don't use `==` operator to compare strings in Java.

Comment: This would fix the problem but it is not the underlying issue.

Comment: too much mistakes in one short line :/